# xml- data protecting from viewers?

Tags: xml

i was wondering what options, or how can i protect my data (which is xml) from people that try to view the files..

Comment: Nine questions and NO accepted answers? Good luck....

Comment: probably because i have bad English and I suck at explaining, or either asking a newbie questions

Comment: This is not an answerable question.

Answer (score 0):

Given how vague the question is, I can only give you vague answers:

1. Don't let them near your data. If your files never leave your computer, no one can view them (unless they have access to your computer).
2. Put your data under a lock and only give the keys to people you trust. The keys can be either something they know (usually username and password), something they own (hardware key, cell phone to which you send an SMS, fingerprint) or a combination of both.
3. Encrypt your data.

Comment: i forgot to add something really important. i meant- how do i do that in C# language

Comment: That doesn't help much. You need to include much more details.